# I R: How to change the class of variable from numeric to character without changing the decimal expansion of the number?

Tags: r, number-formatting, data-conversion

I'd like to know how to change the class of variable from numeric to character without changing the decimal expansion of the number, if I have zeros as the last digits in the number.

On example:

I have a vector x:

```
x <- c(1.00, 2.13, 4.45)
```

And using the as.character function on x:

```
as.character(x)
```

give me the result:

```
"1", "2.13", "4.45"
```

but I want to have result:

```
"1.00", "2.13", "4.45"
```

Thank you in advance for helping me.

Comment: You can't really do this according to the way the original number is typed, but it is possible to set the number of decimal places in the resultant character string. For example, instead of `as.character`, try `sprintf('%.2f', x)` to get two decimal places.

Comment: Those numbers are numerically identical, so the class of the variable is not what's causing it.  What you need to change is how it is being printed.  Are you doing this in the terminal, exporting a table as a PDF, putting into an rmarkdown report or something else?

Comment: `vec <- c(1.00, 2.13, 4.45)` involves R parsing into numeric, which means that your `.00` will be "lost" (the notion that you think there are two significant digits right of the decimal marker). Options: (1) define them as strings the first time, as in `c("1.00", "2.13", "4.45")`; or (2) convert to strings with a specified precision, as in `format(vec, nsmall = 2)` or `sprintf("%0.02f", vec)`.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen I want to write my data frame later as an excel file. And in this file it should be "1.00", not "1". And this is for several columns where it wants to have expansion to different decimal places (but the same in one column).

Comment: @Rafał Excel doesn't store the number of decimal places in the value either, it's a formatting preference set at cell level. What you do in R is going to be largely ignored by Excel.

Comment: HOWEVER, you can tell Excel to format it with two decimal places when exporting from R to Excel. Please check the `openxlsx` package and the `createStyle` function, particularly the "numFmt" argument, where you can simply specify e.g. "0.00".